# how to get root directory folder name in php instead of path

Tags: php

I want to get the root directory folder name in php. I know its possible to get the root directory path using `_DIR_` but i need the folder name. Do we have a php function that can do this? In case the solution is using regular expressions on directory path, is it compatible in all system environments? eg windows, mac, etc.. Basically i dont  want to get  `C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject`\ i want `myProject`.
Here is what i have tried  `$rootDirectoryPath= _DIR_; $rootDirectoryFoldername='';`

Comment: have you tried this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php?

Comment: @DmytroHuz getcwd() return the same path as __DIR__

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate.  Please continue researching.

Comment: check whether it works in windows    or not `basename(getcwd())`

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any built in function to get the `directory of the root path` because you can have really different architecture depending of how you built your application. you have to define it yourself. But if it's always as you define it you can probably doing it using `__DIR__` with an explode and get the last element with the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` as delimiter value to make it works on all file system.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
$projectFolderName = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[1];
```

the   `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns path to current file relative to your root/public
folder of your server. You can then split the string on / which returns array of strings.
First element of that array is the name of your project folder.

When using on different operating systems, You can check presence of / or \ and determine delimiter to use to explode.

```
$delimiter = strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '\\') ? '\\' : '/';
$projectFolderName = explode($delimiter, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])[1];
```

This is one way to do it.

Comment: will it work for `C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject` case ?

Comment: in your case the directory separator is '\', so try explode function with '\'. You'll have to use '\\' as back slash is used to escape quotes.

Comment: so your answer's code is not working in windows but the asker wants a solution for both case or any environment

Comment: I thought he wanted to get the name of project folder. Anyways, to make it work on different systems, there are number of ways you can try this, either check presence of \ or / and explode string depending on that, or if you are using some kind of environment variables file, then add a directory_separator variable there.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) with [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

```
$folderName = substr(strrchr(getcwd(),DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR),1);
```